# Aligning one element to left and other below to right with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm a new Developer, still in the process of learning and have been working on a website for a friend to practice.

I am adding a 'Meet the team' type section on the page and would like it to be displayed as shown in the image linked here:

[image]

- team member 1 photo with bio next to it aligned to the left..
- .. and below that, team member 2 photo with bio next to it aligned to the right.

I've been playing with Flexbox to get this to work but having issues such as having them both appear next to each other so tried adding each team member into their own section to separate the code and that hasn't worked well either.

Code for second issue:

```html
<div class="members">
    <div class="unit">
        <img src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/600/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg">
        <h1>James</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Text</span> Text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="unit">
        <img src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/600/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg">
        <h1>Jamie</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Tet:</span> Text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave you a small example of what you wanted.

The example uses a **flex** rule. Also, I used pseudo-class `:nth-child()` to define a child element in order to assign unique rules for displaying images and text in order.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.unit {
  display: inherit;
  align-items: center;
}

.more {
  display: inherit;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.unit img {
   width: 200px;
   height: auto;
   border-radius: 50%;
}


.unit:nth-child(1) {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.unit:nth-child(2) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="unit">
    <img src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/600/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg">
    <div class="more">
    <h1>James</h1>     
       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
       <ul>
        <li><span>Text</span> Text</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="unit">
    <img src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/600/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg">
    <div class="more">
    <h1>James</h1>     
       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
       <ul>
        <li><span>Text</span> Text</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use the `:odd` and `:even` `nth-child()` selectors?

Comment: @0stone0, What for? This is only used when you have a large collection. But when there are two identical classes, then it is possible without **:odd** and **:even**.

Comment: That's perfect - I knew it had to be a lot simpler than I was making it out to be. Thank you!

Comment: @f8cts, no problem. Glad to help!

Comment: So if you would like a 3th and 4th (+) row, you want to add the `.unit:nth-child(3)` manually?

Comment: @0stone0, I already wrote the answer above to your question. If the collection of selectors is large, and these selectors are dynamic, as an example, then yes, you need to use **odd** and **even**, but when your collection consists of only two **.unit**, then you can do it as I did in my example.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I appear to have an issue with the text now, am I missing something? [Screenshot](https://firealpaca.com/get/4iYAPRNB)

Comment: @f8cts, Show pls how you place this text in html.

Comment: @f8cts, ...and how do you want to place this large text?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov [Screenshot of html](https://firealpaca.com/get/k4XP2Mv8). Ideally want the name, then text below and then list below that, although I will be cutting the list to only a few items. Basically one on top of the other.

Comment: @f8cts, You put all content in `unut`, which has a `flex` rule. Therefore, you get the following result. Paste this code into your question. I'll do it the way you need it.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov ah that makes sense, it would've been fine with just a paragraph but I guess because I have a heading and list too. I've edited my question with the code - thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226987/discussion-between-f8cts-and-s-kuznetsov).

Answer (score 1):

Here You have a Solution with minimal css.
Use `display:flex;` and `justify-content:space-between;` on your **parent** container and use `align-self:flex-end;` property for the **child element on the end**.

```css
#user-data-container{
  width:500px;/*Specify your width here*/
  height:150px;/*specify your height here*/
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
div#last-child{
  align-self:flex-end;
}
#user-data-container>div{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
#first-element{
align-self:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div id="user-data-container">
  <div id="first-element"><img src="https://placehold.it/60/60"/>Text Here</div>
  <div id="last-child">Text Here<img  src="https://placehold.it/60/60"/></div>
</div>
```